# Is there a not increasing function such that $f(f(n))=n+2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(f(n))=n+2$.

In the post [Find all strictly increasing functions on positive integers such that $f(f(n))=n+2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392092) there is an hypothesis about $f$: if $f$ is increasing, then the only solution is $f(n)=n+1$.

But what happen if $f$ is not increasing? Are there another solutions to functional eqution?

Comment: There's a difference between a *non-increasing* function and a function that is merely not an increasing function. Please revise the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:
$$f(n)=\cases{n+3&if $n$ is odd\cr n-1&if $n$ is even.\cr}$$
I am assuming you take $\Bbb N$ to exclude $0$ as in the linked question, which specified $\Bbb N^+$.  But if you want to include $0$ you can create a very similar example.